# Question About Math Symbol

Tags: notation

I want to know what are those symbol that are marked in red...what are their name and functionality?

Consider the finite set of binary strings

{ (000000),(100000),(110000),(111000),(111100),(111110),
  (111111),(011111),(001111),(000111),(000011),(000001) }

Explain how it is possible to represent such a set in a propositional formula
and find the most compact representation.

**Solution.**

**Language** For each 0 ≤ i ≤ 5, bi is a proposition, which intuitively means
that the i-th bit has value 1. Obviously, ¬bi means that the i-th bit does not
have value 1, and thus it has value 0.

**Axioms** A possible (compact) representation of the finite set of binary strings
is given by the following formula:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In terms of logical propositions they are related to $\lor$ (OR) and $\land$ (AND), respectively, as $\sum$ is related to $+$:

$$\bigvee_{k=0}^5a_k=a_0\lor a_1\lor a_2\lor a_3\lor a_4\lor a_5\;,$$

and

$$\bigwedge_{k=0}^5a_k=a_0\land a_1\land a_2\land a_3\land a_4\land a_5\;.$$

In terms of bit strings, however, they are simply bitwise $\sum$ (sum modulo $2$) and $\prod$ (product). If $a_1=01010$, $a_2=11011$, and $a_3=00011$, then

$$\bigvee_{k=1}^3a_k=01010\oplus 11011\oplus 00011=11011\;,$$

where $\oplus$ represents bitwise addition mod $2$, and

$$\bigwedge_{k=1}^3a_k=01010\otimes 11011\otimes 00011=00010\;,$$

where $\otimes$ represents bitwise multiplication.

Comment: Thanks @Brian M. Scott for explaination...I'm little confused about a1 = 01010 how this pattern made?

Comment: @zuby: $01010,11011$, and $00011$ were arbitrarily chosen to illustrate how the operator works; I just made them up for the purpose, so they have nothing to do with the particular strings in your question.

Comment: ok..but I understood those operators...thanks alot...I try to understand that question.

Comment: @zuby: Do you mean that you want to know why the final expression represents the given set of bit strings?

Comment: no...I mean b represents bits like 001011 whereas i-th represets position of a bit in b? also could you explain how first portion in bracket is working in steps?

Comment: could you help me how do I generate output from the formula that's mentioned in question?

Answer (score 1):

You can interpret and name them as the 'logical or' $\lor$ and 'logical and' $\land$ of a range of indexed expressions. Just like $\sum$ is the symbol for a sum.

Comment: Thanks @Pieter21 for your response.